# Slope ≠ 1 in Henderson-Hasselbalch graph for determination of pKa

Tags: analytical-chemistry, spectrophotometry, henderson-hasselbalch-equation

[image: Graph 1]

The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of indicators can be determined via plotting a graph of $\log \left(\frac{\ce{In-}}{\ce{HIn}}\right)$  vs $\mathrm{pH}$ with the help of a spectrophotometer, from the equation $\log \left(\frac{\ce{In-}}{\ce{HIn}}\right) = \mathrm{pH} - \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$.

From this, the graph should have a gradient of 1, and $x$-intercept = -($y$-intercept) = $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$. However, my graph has a slope of ~0.8 which means my $x$-intercept ≠ -($y$-intercept) so which value do I use as my calculated $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$?

From the papers I've read, most if not all of them use the intercept with the $\mathrm{pH}$ axis instead of the $\log \left(\frac{\ce{In-}}{\ce{HIn}}\right)$  axis in this situation, why is this?

Comment: What exactly did you measure with spectrophotometer, and can you post a picture of the plot?

Comment: The spectrophotometer was used to measure the absorption at 592nm of bromophenol blue at different pH's

Comment: So how do you transform the measured absorption at $\pu{592 nm}$  into two values, namely $\ce{ [HI]}$ and $\ce{[I-]}$ ?

Comment: Your term of $\log \left(\frac{\ce{I-}}{\ce{HI}}\right)$ is misleading.

Comment: I wasn't sure about your techniques. But according to the graphs and the equation, when $\log \left(\frac{\ce{In-}}{\ce{HIn}}\right) = 0$, $\mathrm{pH} = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} $.

Comment: From The Merck Index, bromophenol blue has a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ equal to $4.0$. And the curve displays $4.2$

Comment: We determined log([I-]/[HI]) as follows: At a particular wavelength, the absorption of the acid form is Aa while the absorbance of the base form is Ab. The absorbance of the mixture is therefore A=FaAa + FbAb where Fa and Fb are the fractions of the indicator in the acid and base forms respectivly. It can then be shown by rearrangement and substitution that [I-]/[HI] = (A-Aa)/(Ab-A). It has been assumed that only the base form of the indicator absorbs at 592nm, thus at this λ, Aa≈0. So [I-]/[HI] = A/Ab-A

Answer (score 2):

> **OP's question:** From the papers I've read, most if not all of them use the intercept with the $\mathrm{pH}$ axis instead of the $\log \left(\frac{\ce{In-}}{\ce{HIn}}\right)$ axis in this situation, why is this?

Answer for this question is easy. According to the graphs plotted using the equation $\log \left(\frac{\ce{In-}}{\ce{HIn}}\right) = \mathrm{pH} - \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ (Henderson-Hasslebalch equation), when $\log \left(\frac{\ce{In-}}{\ce{HIn}}\right) = 0$ (meaning $[\ce{In-}] = [\ce{HIn}]$), then $\mathrm{pH} = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} $. Therefore, the $x$-value where the straight-line crosses the $x$-axis is the best value for $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} $.

Comment: It is not exactly a straight line (experimental data, no information on error bars). Nice explanation why to focus on the x-intercept.